# DWG unable to load with new viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Previously I used this viewer script which used to load dwg correctly

`<script src="https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/2.5/viewer3D.min.js"></script>`

Now am following this tutorial to setup an initial viewer:

https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/basic-viewer/

Now none of my files are getting loaded on viewer. Viewer just show's animated loader and is not able to load the files. When I changed the viewer from:

`<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.min.js"></script>`

to:

`<script src="https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/2.5/viewer3D.min.js"></script>`

the file gets load in that viewer.

And their is no example about how to use Markup API. Could Anyone Please provide an example.

Comment: Sorry it's not clear which JS URL is working and which isn't... can you describe better?

Comment: This Url doesnt work `<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I did test it and it's working. Make sure you have HTTPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest codebase for The Viewer can be included from [Autodesk’s CDN](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/basics/). I did tested and it's live. Please also check this [tutorial](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/basic-viewer/).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/style.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/A360.css" type="text/css">

<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/Autodesk360App.js"></script>
```

Comment: And what about Markups can you please provide an example now when i am doing `console.log(Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions)` it doesn't provide Markups method.

Comment: The markup extension has to be included by referencing another script: https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/2.5/extensions/MarkupsCore.js. See my blog post for more info: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/02/playing-with-the-new-view-data-markup-api.html